# Canvas App Previewer stuck on Loading

Tags: canvas, canvas-app

Last week I created my first canvas app, and then promptly struggled to get it to appear in Salesforce until I found out that sessions established through `frontdoor.jsp` don't work with it. It did work when I created a password for my Scratch org user and authenticated with that.

That aside, it always loaded in the Cavas App Previewer under setup. Today the app wouldn't seem to work at all, and so in a different developer org I created a new Canvas connected app as an experiement, and that also won't load, just appearing like so in the previewer:

[image: Image of Canvas App Previewer showing the loading spinner]

The org was updated to the Summer release on the 10th of June, so prior to my earlier experiemnts and I don't think that's to blame, but I have no idea why it's failing now. Has anybody else seen this or have a working canvas app they can verify?